# Программа не видит файлы которые находятся в архиве

Tags: java, io, zip

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Программа не видит файлы которые находятся в архиве, подскажите в чем моя проблема? То есть entry = null

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Archive.zip");
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
    ZipEntry entry;
    try {
        while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Extracting: " + entry);
            int count;
            byte data[] = new byte[2048];
            // Write the files to the disk
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(entry.getName());
            BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 2048);
            while ((count = zis.read(data, 0, 2048)) != -1) {
                dest.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            dest.flush();
            dest.close();
            zis.closeEntry();
        }
    } finally {
        zis.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Насколько я вижу, сам код корректен. Подозреваю, что дело в архиве. Zip-архивы созданные разными средствами могут отличаться друг от друга внутренним строением. И, скорее всего, мы наблюдаем случай, когда читалка zip-потока в java просто не знает, как работать со структурой вашего файла Archive.zip. Поэтому и получается null. Попробуйте создать zip-файл средствами Windows (Выделите файлы -> Правая кнопка мыши - Send to compressed folder). И прогоните программу по такому архиву.

Comment: Проверил сейчас, всё верно. У меня распаковывается без проблем архив созданный системными средствами windows и ubuntu. А winrar у меня не установлен. Так что скорее всего дело в архиве. Сам код работает.